# Paste Special in Active Cell using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, copy-paste

I want to copy a table (range A1 to AV3) from Worksheet 2 to Active Cell in Worksheet 1

my current code is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:AV3").Copy
Worksheets("Sheet1).ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
Worksheets("Sheet1").ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
End Sub
```

can anyone help me to fix this?
I want every time I click the button, it will copy to any active cell.

Comment: If *Sheet1* is not "Active", then `ActiveCell` will not be on that sheet.

Comment: the button is on Sheet 1
so Sheet1 will be active when I click the button..

Comment: you are missing a little `"` at the end of `Worksheets("Sheet1).ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats` , should be `Worksheets("Sheet1").ActiveCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats`

Comment: ah, already fix that, but still cant paste the table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your `ActiveCell` is in "Sheet1", and the Command-Button is also in "Sheet1", there's no need to add `Worksheets("Sheet1")` before `ActiveCell`, just use something like the code below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:AV3").Copy
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
ActiveCell.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End Sub
```

Comment: @RosyaChairani just make sure your `ActiveCell` is indeed in "Sheet1"

Comment: @ShaiRado - Wouldn't the activecell **have** to be on Sheet1 if the user was clicking a button on Sheet1 (the button code is on Sheet1's codesheet)? Baring someone trying to programatically 'click' the private sub on Sheet1's codesheet when another worksheet was active of course. I suppose that it could fail if an object was selected however.

Comment: @Jeeped  I was able to have activecell in "sheet2" and press the button on "sheet1", i guess it's not reasonable, but before I get some "wise" comments here I added that

Comment: Yes, I suppose that extra thoroughness is necessary to validate the solution. Good answer btw.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way that I have found is to replace the Ctrl+v with my own macro.

```
    Sub Paste_Values()

    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

    End Sub
```

Comment: This will fail if `Selection` is not a Range, or produce spurious content if your Selection is a Multi-Area Range.  `Selection` is not the same as `ActiveCell`

Answer (score 0):

John's suggestion worked perfectly for me.

At the end of my list, I am adding xx and then I use find xx followed by John's suggested string:

```
Sheets("Sheet 2").Select
Cells.Find(What:="xx", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas2, LookAt:= _
    xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False _
    , SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```